# How to install python and gobject runtime in Yocto / OpenEmbeded?

Tags: python-3.x, yocto, openembedded, poppler, gobject-introspection

My helloword code:

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Poppler', '0.18')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Poppler, Gtk

def draw(vp, surface):
    surface.set_source_rgb(0.7, 0.7, 0.7)
    surface.paint()
    size = page.get_size()
  
    surface.set_source_rgb(1, 1, 1)
    surface.rectangle(0,0, *size)
    surface.fill()
    
    
    page.render_for_printing(surface)

document = Poppler.Document.new_from_file("file:///home/eri/invoice-V6605371.pdf", None)
n = document.get_n_pages()
page = document.get_page(0)

window = Gtk.Window(title="View", resizable=False, decorated=False )

sc = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
window.add(sc)


window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

vp = Gtk.Viewport()
vp.set_app_paintable(True)
vp.connect("draw", draw)
sc.add(vp)

window.maximize()
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

How to install runtime for it in Yocto / OpenEmbeded?

I have `/usr/lib/girepository-1.0/` in rootfs after

```
MACHINE_FEATURES_append = " qemu-usermode "
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " gobject-introspection-data "
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. You need what exactly, python and gobject-introspection?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk i need run script from question

Comment: and what exactly do you need to run it?

Comment: seems i solved it. waiting `do_compile`

Comment: Poppler not in gi-repository. I changed it to Evince